# Is there any advantage of using django with tornado

Tags: django, tornado

Just curious after reading [this](https://github.com/bdarnell/django-tornado-demo/blob/master/testsite/tornado_main.py), it wraps django using tornado. Is there any advantage or disadvantage of using tornado on django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest advantage is if you have an existing django codebase that you would like to enhance with some async operations.  Tornado is a lean framework where DB Models, Django level templating, middleware, etc.etc. are not present.

That said, if you are starting from scratch on a project mixing Tornado + BackboneJS will yield a much more interesting application.

Comment: Ok, so there're no cons? Because i thought django suppose to be synchronous and tornado async